# Connection error while reading zoho email using mail-listerner2

Tags: node.js, imap, zoho

I am getting error when i try to connect with zoho mail using mail-listener2, But i can able to connect and read mail from my application using node-imap. Please help me on this issue.

The config param i am using with node-imap is as below

```
var imap = new Imap({
    user: nconf.get('IMAP_USER'),
    password: nconf.get('IMAP_PASS'),
    host: nconf.get('IMAP_HOST'),
    port: nconf.get('IMAP_PORT'),
    connTimeout: 10000000,
    tls: true
});
```

Same param i am using with mail-listener2 but getting the below error

> { [Error: No supported authentication method(s) available. Unable to
>   login.] source: 'authentication' }

Comment: Are you using SSL or STARTTLS security?  if not, it likely won't allow you to login insecurely.

Comment: @j1s I have the same problem, have you fixed it?

Comment: try 'username' instead of 'user'